# Ruby Daemons log rotation

Tags: ruby, rubygems, daemons

When I'm setting logging parameters to the Daemons (1.1.0) gem, how would I achieve similar behavior to this line?

```
logger = Logger.new('foo.log', 10, 1024000)
```

Daemon options:

```
options = {
      :ARGV         => ['start'],
      :dir_mode     => :normal, 
      :dir          => log_dir,
      :multiple     => false,
      :ontop        => false
      :mode         => :exec,
      :backtrace    => true,
      :log_output   => true
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately the Daemons gem does not use Logger. It redirects `STDOUT` and `STDERR` directly to a file.

You can see the details of how the redirection works here:
https://github.com/ghazel/daemons/blob/master/lib/daemons/daemonize.rb#L241-261

Because of this, you will have to use something like [logrotate](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html) and restart the daemon if you want to do log file rotation.

If this is not acceptable, I would suggest using `Logger` directly like you provided in the question.